# How an CPU finds location of a variable

Tags: c++, c

I am working with C++(Sorry,If my question is little bit confusing).I know how pointer works.It points to an address of a variable.
My Question is that if I have created a simple variable(not a pointer) in stack or heap.How does CPU find the address of a variable as there is no pointer is present which points to that variable.It is just a name of an address in Memory.
for e.g

```
  int main()
    {
        int a=5;//Created a variable by allocating 4 bytes
        return 0;
    }
```

It created a variable but Question is how will CPU find the variable?

Comment: "Variables" are a high-level notion that are part of a *programming language*. The operating system or your hardware have no concept of "variables".

Comment: The OS does not need to find the variable. The OS gives a process access to the CPU and certain chunks of memory. One of those is used as a stack by the compiled program.

Comment: The operating system is not involved at all, it's all up to the compiler to handle local variables and where in memory it should be placed.

Comment: Your compiler maybe going to remove that line itself. :-)

Comment: I did not have concept of how Operating System Works or what runs my program.I just knew my program is compiled and run.

Comment: @user36734 - Please do not edit a question in that way - the comments now do not make any sense

Comment: Apart from points mentioned in previous comments, even if you do not have a pointer to that variable, this variable has an address. Simply use `&a` to get this address.

Comment: Sir, tobi303 My Question is that How this address is accessed?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that you can always access this address with `&a` (no need to declare a pointer). What happens in the cpu is a different story

Comment: It's going to be impossible to thoroughly teach you the answer to this without you fundamentally understanding what compilers are and what they do. And how.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26267735/46642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have some concept misunderstanding. In every program, there is a memory area called **stack** where local variables are allocated. In most computer architectures, there is a register called **stack pointer** (*rsp* in the x86_64 architecture) which points at the top of the stack (which grows from higher memory addresses to lower addresses).

In execution time, **the program code** (generated by the compiler, and not the OS) uses this stack pointer as the base to allocate its local variables. So your code **would move the number 5** itself to a location that's pointed by the current value of the stack pointer at the moment when `main()` was called, with an offset of 4 bytes (the location pointed by the current sp register is not known at all, because it is changing all the time with every function call).

Comment: Does it also means that the last variable created should be on the top of the stack and is accessed first?

Comment: @user36734: It doesn't have to be. It's called a stack because the stack _frame_ for the current function is on top of the stack and is accessed "first". The details of each local variable are _within_ the stack frame and so are not really relevant to the stack's algorithmic operation.

Answer (score 0):

> How does CPU find the address of a variable as there is no pointer is present which points to that variable.It is just a name of an address in Memory.

This is not true. In fact it is the opposite of true.

In your executable, your compiler has written the address of the variable (or a relative offset from the current stack frame, anyway) and machine instructions that describe how to use it. The name is not present at all.

And that's how your CPU knows how to find the variable: the variable does not exist any more at runtime! It is an abstraction of C++, provided to you the programmer to make your life easier. But it bears little to no relationship to how the *actual* computer program *actually* works and how your CPU executes it.